# ElasticSearch Nested Query Does not work as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, nest, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I need a quick help, i need to fetch the entire document only when my certain conditions are fulfilled in that same array.

**Example**

Conditions when in one array block all these three conditions fulfill. i.e.

- "profile.bud.buddies.code": "1"
- "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.key":"one"
- "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.val": "0"

Unfortunately right now it is going through the entire document and trying to match the values in each of those arrays so it could be so that code=1 gets matched in one array, key=one in some other array and val=0 in the third array. What happens it in this case it returns me the entire document, whereas actually this was not fulfilled in one array alone so shouldn't have returned me the document.

I made the **moredata** as nested type but still cannot get through. Please help.

**Query I am using**

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "profile.bud.buddies.code": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "nested": {
    "path": "profile.bud.buddies.moredata",
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.key": "one"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.val": "0"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Document Structure**

```
"profile": {
  "x":{},
  "y":{},
  "a":{},
  "b":{},
  "bud":{
    "buddies": [
    {
        "code":"1",
        "moredata": [
            {
                "key": "one",
                "val": 0,
                "setup": "2323",
                "data": "myid"
            },
            {
                "key": "two",
                "val": 1,
                "setup": "23",
                "data": "id"
            }]
    },
    {
        "code":"2",
        "moredata": [
            {
                "key": "two",
                "val": 0,
                "setup": "2323",
                "data": "myid"
            },
            {
                "key": "three",
                "val": 1,
                "setup": "23",
                "data": "id"
            }]
    }]
}
```

This is how i have marked the mappings;

```
"profile": {
"bug": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "buddies": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "moredata": {
                                                "type": "nested",
                                                "properties": {
                            "key": {"type": "string"},
                            "val": {"type": "string"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query structure is incorrect, it should be something like

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [{
        "match": {
          "profile.bud.buddies.code": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "profile.bud.buddies.moredata",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [{
                  "match": {
                    "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.key": "one"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "profile.bud.buddies.moredata.val": "0"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

where the `nested` query is inside of the array of `must` clauses of the outer `bool` query. Note that `profile.bud.buddies.moredata` must be mapped as a `nested` data type.

Comment: Thanks - getting following error Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 660

Comment: Sorted the issue, just needed to move the ] one level down.

Comment: All the queries are `should` clauses, so only one needs to match. I think they should be either `must` or `filter` clauses?

Comment: Did not get you

Comment: In your question description, you say that all the conditions need to be fulfilled. If the queries are in the `should` clause of a `bool` query, then only one query needs to match for the document to be returned in the response. If all queries need to be satisfied, then the queries should be in either the `must` clauses or `filter` clauses of the `bool` query.

Comment: Oh - thanks a lot for the help - I get it now and you have solved my query.